# How to make Elasticsearch indexing "blocking" when testing with Python?

Tags: python, testing, elasticsearch

I have few new microservices that use Elasticsearch to pass and retrieve data and I want to have few integration tests that use ES. The problem I have is getting data after some_document.save(). I have to have like sleep(1) for the get to retrieve the data via tested code.

Is there a way to make it blocking/synchronous to not use sleep in tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is it take time to refresh the index.

What you can do is refresh it manually (in the code) instead of sleep.

```
POST /_refresh 
POST /<index>/_refresh
```

If it's on the same machine as the code then use :

```
import requests
requests.post('localhost:9200/<index>/_refresh')
```

Comment: Index('the index').refresh() and it seems to be working. Thanks.